# How to use the ThumbnailCard in IDialog Context

Tags: bots, botframework

Hi I am developing one bot using Microsoft `botframework` project in that I am using `IDialog` interface. In that I am using the `ThumbnailCard` for displaying the cards. Here when I am attaching some data to my cards and the data is attaching properly but within the `PostAsync` method it’s not providing the reply.

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        ThumbnailCard plCard = null;
        IMessageActivity replyToConversation =await argument;
        replyToConversation.Type = "message";
        replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        replyToConversation.Text = "welcome to book my show";
        Dictionary<string, string> cardContentList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        cardContentList.Add("Jason Bourne", "URL");
        cardContentList.Add("The Land", "URL");
        cardContentList.Add("Yoga Hosers", "URL");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cardContent in cardContentList)
        {
            List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
            cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: cardContent.Value));
            List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
            if (cardContent.Key == "Jason Bourne")
            {
                CardAction plButton1 = new CardAction()
                {
                     Value = $"",
                    Type = "openUrl",
                    Title = "Book Now"
                };

                CardAction plButton2 = new CardAction()
                {
                    Value = "tel:1-800-800-5705",
                    Type = "call",
                    Title = "Show timings"
                };
                cardButtons.Add(plButton1);
                cardButtons.Add(plButton2);

                plCard = new ThumbnailCard()
                {
                    Title = $"Jason Bourne",
                    Subtitle = " ",
                    Images = cardImages,
                    Buttons = cardButtons,

                };
                Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
            }
            else if (cardContent.Key == "The Land")
            {
                CardAction plButton1 = new CardAction()
                {
                     Value = $"",
                    Type = "openUrl",
                    Title = "Book Now"
                };
                CardAction plButton2 = new CardAction()
                {
                    Value = "tel:1-800-800-5705",
                    Type = "call",
                    Title = "Show Timings"
                };
                cardButtons.Add(plButton1);
                cardButtons.Add(plButton2);

                plCard = new ThumbnailCard()
                {
                    Title = $"The Land",
                    Subtitle = "",
                    Images = cardImages,
                    Buttons = cardButtons,

                };
                Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
            }
            else if (cardContent.Key == "Yoga Hosers")
            {

                CardAction plButton1 = new CardAction()
                {
                     Value = $"",
                    Type = "openUrl",
                    Title = "Book Now"
                };
                CardAction plButton2 = new CardAction()
                {
                    Value = "tel:1-800-800-5705",
                    Type = "call",
                    Title = "Show timings"
                };
                cardButtons.Add(plButton1);
                cardButtons.Add(plButton2);

                plCard = new ThumbnailCard()
                {
                    Title = $"Yoga Hosers",
                    Subtitle = "",
                    Images = cardImages,
                    Buttons = cardButtons,
                };
                Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
            }
        }
        replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
    }
```

When I run the bot its show the following error 
[image]

Can we use cards in **IDialog Context** for attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the IMessageActivity, you are trying to send IMessageActicity in context.PostAsync. That's the reason it is failing.

Do the following changes to make it work

Change the method signature like below

```
private async Task messageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> argument)
```

and modify the `IMessageActivity replyToConversation =await argument;` to like below

```
var message = await argument as Activity;           
        Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply("Welcome." + "(Hi)");
        replyToConversation.Recipient = message.From;
```

Now it should work, if you still have issue please comment here.

-Kishore

Comment: Thanks Kishore and thanks for your suggestion and now my code is working properly